# android: Icsspinner outside of ActionBar not showing drop down

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a spinner which works perfectly and is getting populated with data only for AVDs with API 15 and 16. But With API level 8 and 10, it is not showing the drop down list. I am using ActionBarSherlock.

```
  String[] categoryFixed = { "Mortgage/Rent", "Utilities",
            "Car Payments", "Insurance", "Misc" };       

         IcsSpinner category =(IcsSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, categoryFixed);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

        category.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is my spinner

```
           <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            />
```

Is there anything I am missing here specifically?

Comment: where strings.xml file located in res dir?

Comment: `IcsSpinner` is not for use outside of ActionBarSherlock. It is in the `internal` package for a reason!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on Android 2.2 and it worked fine. Make sure the string array is located in `values` directory, versus `values-v11`, or `values-v14`

Comment: I figured out that it was not showing up because I am using ActionBarSherlock. So I used the IcsSpinner outside of ActionBar. But I am still not getting the dropdown. I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
```

instead of

```
<Spinner
```

in the xml file.